# If the integer pointed to by num begins with or contains 3

Tags: python, if-statement

If the integer pointed to by num begins with or contains 3

please tell me how to code this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try converting the number to a string and then check, like this

```py
some_num = 34566
# str(some_num) return the number in string i.e returns '34566'
if (len(str(some_num)) > 0 and ('3' in str(some_num)): print(True)
```

Comment: thank you sir. if integer starts with 3 ,how can i code this? (ex.30,300,34)

Comment: `len(str(some_num)) > 0` is redundant.